# MySQL Database's tables corrupted

Tags: mysql, database, corrupt

After checking my Database with PHPMyAdmin, I found that some tables are corrupted and no more readable, my forum crashed.

Using REPAIR function did not solve the problem.

I tried to manipulate my DB with SSH by using:

```
REPAIR table my_table;
```

Result:

> Error -> Operation failed -> 0 for record at pos 291290000

Following some stackoverflow answers, I used :

```
myisamchk -r <table_name>
```

But I got error as like this command do not exist.

Any idea how to solve this problem ?

**[UPDATE]**

I was able to repair all tables with:

```
repair table ibf_sessions;
```

and some others by adding *use_frm*:

```
repair table ibf_sessions use_frm;
```

except one table "ibf_posts" that still generate errors while repairing:

```
+--------------------+--------+----------+-----------------------+
| Table              | Op     | Msg_type | Msg_text              |
+--------------------+--------+----------+-----------------------+
| cssforum.ibf_posts | repair | error    | 127 when fixing table |
| cssforum.ibf_posts | repair | status   | Operation failed      |
+--------------------+--------+----------+-----------------------+
```

Any idea ?

**[EDIT 2]**

Problem solved with this way for the table that I couldn't repair with REPAIR command. May be it will helps someone:

> 1. DB exported
> 2. DB imported locally (and it succeeded).
> 3. DB exported again to the remote server.

Comment: I don't have the answer for this problem but I suggest you grab the SA and ask them to get a copy of the latest backup handy.

Comment: No backup founded since long time. This will not solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: You are in serious trouble I guess.

Comment: Try exporting all the records to csv and create a new table with it of the same name.